# using to being instead of to be

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

recently i saw a strange sentence about Ronaldo, but I could not understand it's grammer:

> Portugal coach 'really didn't like' Ronaldo's reaction **to being subbed off**

i do not understand why they used **to** **being** instead of using **to be**.

Comment: You react to a thing (a noun), not a verb.

Comment: So **being subbed off** was the incident to which Ronaldo reacted badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English you react to things. Things are nouns. The phrase "being subbed off" is a **[gerund](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund)**, a form of a verb that acts like a noun. It's the noun for the *action* of subbing someone off.

Note that the "to" is not the infinitive, it's the preposition that indicates what the reaction is about. If we replace the gerund (noun) "being subbed off" with other nouns we get (for example):

> Portugal coach 'really didn't like' Ronaldo's reaction to *the picture*.

*The picture* is a noun and replaces the noun "being subbed off".